# Random reboots on 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 20.04, hardware, reboot

For the past few days. my laptop reboots randomly without warning and at different intervals. It only shows me a black screen and restarts the PC. I don't thinks it's the CPU temperature because the PC feels very cold.

I performed a memory and drive test on the BIOS and both of them passed. I suspect that it is related to the network card because every time the PC restarts randomly the wifi disappears afterwards and it only allows connection through the ethernet. Is there any way I can fix it?

Here is my laptop temperature, with the sensors command:

```
fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:       12.42 mW (avg =   8.53 mW, interval =   0.01 s)
                       (crit =  15.00 W)

BAT1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.10 V  
curr1:            N/A  

amdgpu-pci-0008
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:        1.55 V  
vddnb:       775.00 mV 
edge:         +51.0°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +51.2°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +99.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +226.8°C)
temp2:        +20.0°C
```

I was advised to check `/var/log/syslog` and this what happen when it randomly rebooted last time:

```
    Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx avahi-daemon[752]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx whoopsie[1010]: [00:10:29] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx NetworkManager[757]: <info>  [1632899429.1105] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx NetworkManager[757]: <info>  [1632899429.1105] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed bound -> done
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx NetworkManager[757]: <info>  [1632899429.1112] dhcp6 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx avahi-daemon[752]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.68 on wlo1.
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx NetworkManager[757]: <info>  [1632899429.1112] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed bound -> done
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx avahi-daemon[752]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.68.
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx avahi-daemon[752]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx NetworkManager[757]: <info>  [1632899429.1433] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx gnome-shell[1725]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx nm-dispatcher[9629]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx gnome-shell[1725]: g_dbus_connection_emit_signal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx gnome-shell[1725]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx gnome-shell[1725]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx kernel: [ 3220.742179] rtw_8723de 0000:03:00.0: stop vif dc:f5:05:8b:6d:c3 on port 0
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx wpa_supplicant[795]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx gnome-shell[1725]: Error adding children to desktop: desktopGrid is undefined
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx kernel: [ 3221.365180] usb usb2-port3: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx kernel: [ 3221.365202] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 18
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx gnome-shell[1725]: Error adding children to desktop: desktopGrid is undefined
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx gvfsd[9555]: PTP: reading event an error 0x05 occurred
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx udisksd[794]: Cleaning up mount point /media/julio/HiSuite (device 11:1 no longer exists)
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx udisksd[794]: Error inhibiting: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running (g-io-error-quark, 36)
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/julio/HiSuite...
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1478]: media-julio-HiSuite.mount: Succeeded.
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx umount[9646]: umount: /media/julio/HiSuite: no montado.
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx dbus-daemon[1488]: [session uid=1000 pid=1488] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=1486 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Sep 29 00:10:29 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1478]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Sep 29 00:10:30 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: media-julio-HiSuite.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Sep 29 00:10:30 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: media-julio-HiSuite.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 29 00:10:30 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/julio/HiSuite.
Sep 29 00:10:30 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Stopping Clean the /media/julio/HiSuite mount point...
Sep 29 00:10:30 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: clean-mount-point@media-julio-HiSuite.service: Succeeded.
Sep 29 00:10:30 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Stopped Clean the /media/julio/HiSuite mount point.
Sep 29 00:10:30 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx dbus-daemon[1488]: [session uid=1000 pid=1488] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Sep 29 00:10:30 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1478]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Sep 29 00:10:30 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx kernel: [ 3221.656482] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
Sep 29 00:10:31 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx gvfsd[9555]: Device 0 (VID=12d1 and PID=1082) is a Huawei Ascend P8.
Sep 29 00:10:31 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx gvfsd[9555]: Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Sep 29 00:10:32 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 29 00:10:32 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Sep 29 00:10:32 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Sep 29 00:10:32 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd-sleep[9669]: Suspending system...
Sep 29 00:10:32 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx kernel: [ 3224.334705] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Sep 29 00:10:33 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Succeeded.
Sep 29 00:10:33 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Sep 29 00:10:33 julio-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\
```

Comment: You can not feel the temp of the CPU with your hand. The most common item to overheat and cause a reboot or shut down. Not saying that is the issue.

Comment: I left an edit with my sensors stats, just in case

Comment: If the WiFi consistently disappears before the reboot, there should be something in `/var/log/syslog` that reports an error involving that device. Take a look and see if there are core dumps or other messages that force the machine to restart.

Comment: I already uptaded the post with /var/log/syslog  results when it last randomly rebooted

Comment: That output looks to me like a crash while suspending. The system carefully unmounts storage, reaches sleep, proceeds toward suspend, then crashes.

Comment: Any specific that may cause it? So I can try to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for updating me. I already fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to fix it. It turns out it was the "ACPI bios error" who was rebooting the PC.

I fixed it by editing the configuration file for GRUB:

Open the file as root, for example by running

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` to include the parameter `libata.noacpi=1`, so that after your edit it says, for example

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="libata.noacpi=1"
```

Save the file and exit, then run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and it should work fine.