# Random suspensions of Ubuntu 22

Tags: power-management, asus, 22.04, amd-ryzen

I recently completed a new build with ryzen 5900x, ASUS ROG strix B550-F and RTX 3060. I'm going to use this machine as workstation as a ML software engeneer. I installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS and updatedthe bios of the mobo to the latest version.

The problem is the following: after few MINUTES of inactivity the pc goes to sleep even if the conditions in settings are not matched:

[Screen of the settings app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4VlH.png)

I found this therad familiar: [Ubuntu 20.04 suspends when idle, even if relevant power settings are disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237846/ubuntu-20-04-suspends-when-idle-even-if-relevant-power-settings-are-disabled). So I applied the solution suggested but now I don't have the opportunity to sleep my pc anymore (I was aware of that). I would like to know if this is a common problem and if anyone of you found a valid solution.

Within 5 minutes of an event "going to sleep", the terminal command `sudo journalctl --since="-6 minutes"` gives the following output:

```
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1652798836.5240] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler ModemManager[877]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1652798836.5240] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler gnome-shell[2104]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler gnome-shell[2104]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler gnome-shell[2104]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler gnome-shell[2104]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler gnome-shell[2104]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler gnome-shell[2104]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
mag 17 16:47:16 kepler gsd-media-keys[2459]: Unable to get default sink
```

The solution proposed by @ManOnTheMoon seems to solve the problem.

I added the option `libata.noacpi=1` to the grub file: `/etc/default/grub`.

The final string is thus the follow:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.noacpi=1"`

I still need some more testing but my pc won't suspend anymore.

I'm curious to understand... is this due to a configuration error in the bios energy profile or is just related to the grub configuration?

UPDATE:

Also after the proposed modification the system goes in sleep mode after few minutes:

Here some logs after the sleep event...

```
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler suspend[3481]: nvidia-suspend.service
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler logger[3481]: <13>May 17 21:14:30 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "40"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "43"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event6  - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION: device removed
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event10 - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION Mouse: device removed
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event7  - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION Consumer Control: device removed
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "47"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event8  - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION System Control: device removed
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event11 - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION: device removed
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "50"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event3  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device removed
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event2  - Logitech G305: device removed
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler rtkit-daemon[1256]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler rtkit-daemon[1256]: Successfully made thread 3497 of process 1976 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler rtkit-daemon[1256]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:74
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:75
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
mag 17 21:14:30 kepler kernel: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 90
mag 17 21:14:31 kepler systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
mag 17 21:14:31 kepler systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
mag 17 21:14:31 kepler systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
mag 17 21:14:31 kepler systemd-sleep[3498]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
mag 17 21:14:31 kepler kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.001 seconds
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: OOM killer disabled.
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 12 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP off
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 13 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 14 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 15 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 16 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 17 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 18 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 19 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 20 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 21 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 22 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: CPU 23 is now offline
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU1 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU2 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU3 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x8
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU4: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU4 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0xa
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU5: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU5 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x10
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU6: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU6 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x12
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU7: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU7 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x14
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU8: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU8 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x16
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU9: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU9 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x18
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU10: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU10 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0x1a
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU11: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU11 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 12 APIC 0x1
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU12: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP always-on
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU12 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 13 APIC 0x3
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU13: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU13 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 14 APIC 0x5
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU14: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU14 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 15 APIC 0x7
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU15: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU15 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 16 APIC 0x9
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU16: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU16 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 17 APIC 0xb
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU17: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU17 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 18 APIC 0x11
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU18: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU18 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 19 APIC 0x13
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU19: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU19 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 20 APIC 0x15
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU20: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU20 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 21 APIC 0x17
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU21: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU21 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 22 APIC 0x19
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU22: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU22 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 23 APIC 0x1b
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: microcode: CPU23: patch_level=0x0a201205
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: CPU23 is up
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: nvme nvme0: 32/0/0 default/read/poll queues
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: usb 1-7: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: usb 1-9: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: usb 1-10: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: OOM killer enabled.
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler kernel: PM: suspend exit
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler systemd-resolved[727]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler acpid[787]: client 2134[1000:1000] has disconnected
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler systemd-sleep[3498]: System returned from sleep state.
mag 17 21:14:36 kepler systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler rtkit-daemon[1256]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:65
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler suspend[3654]: nvidia-resume.service
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler logger[3654]: <13>May 17 21:14:37 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Deactivated successfully.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system resume actions.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler rtkit-daemon[1256]: Successfully made thread 3653 of process 1976 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler rtkit-daemon[1256]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): connected
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler gsd-media-keys[2453]: Unable to get default sink
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler acpid[787]: client connected from 2134[1000:1000]
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler acpid[787]: 1 client rule loaded
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler rtkit-daemon[1256]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler rtkit-daemon[1256]: Successfully made thread 3656 of process 1976 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler rtkit-daemon[1256]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:70
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event6  - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event6  - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION: device is a keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:67
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event3  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event3  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:74
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event10 - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event10 - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION Mouse: device is a pointer
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:72
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event8  - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION System Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event8  - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION System Control: device is a keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:71
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event7  - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event7  - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:75
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event11 - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event11 - ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION: device is a keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:64
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd-logind[811]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler ModemManager[841]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is resuming
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814877.9317] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:66
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814877.9317] device (enp6s0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event2  - Logitech G305: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event2  - Logitech G305: device is a pointer
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (II) event2  - Logitech G305: device is a keyboard
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814877.9669] dhcp4 (enp6s0): canceled DHCP transaction
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814877.9669] dhcp4 (enp6s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814877.9669] dhcp4 (enp6s0): state changed no lease
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler avahi-daemon[790]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.17 on enp6s0.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814877.9670] dhcp6 (enp6s0): canceled DHCP transaction
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler avahi-daemon[790]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp6s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.17.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814877.9670] dhcp6 (enp6s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler avahi-daemon[790]: Interface enp6s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814877.9670] dhcp6 (enp6s0): state changed no lease
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler avahi-daemon[790]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::8886:80db:1519:6d6c on enp6s0.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd-resolved[727]: enp6s0: Bus client reset search domain list.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler avahi-daemon[790]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp6s0.IPv6 with address fe80::8886:80db:1519:6d6c.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd-resolved[727]: enp6s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler avahi-daemon[790]: Interface enp6s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
mag 17 21:14:37 kepler systemd-resolved[727]: enp6s0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814878.0150] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler geoclue[1539]: Failed to query location: Error resolving “location.services.mozilla.com”: Temporary failure in name resolution
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler NetworkManager[795]: <info>  [1652814878.0959] device (enp6s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler dbus-daemon[793]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=795 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler dbus-daemon[793]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4074.0009: HID++ 4.2 device connected.
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler gnome-shell[2337]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler gnome-shell[2337]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
mag 17 21:14:38 kepler upowerd[1373]: treated changed event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2/0003:046D:C53F.0004/0003:046D:4074.0009/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
mag 17 21:14:39 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): connected
mag 17 21:14:39 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
mag 17 21:14:39 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mag 17 21:14:39 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mag 17 21:14:39 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): connected
mag 17 21:14:39 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
mag 17 21:14:39 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mag 17 21:14:39 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mag 17 21:14:40 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): connected
mag 17 21:14:40 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
mag 17 21:14:40 kepler /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2134]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Microstep MSI MD271QP (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
```

Due to the numerous logs related to the nvidia driver I tried to use the open noveau drivers, using the additional driver tabs, instead the suggested 510.60. In this case the suspension problem disappears definitely.

So this is related to the nvidia drivers. I noticed that there are newer drivers (510.73.05) actually not present in the ubuntu repository. According to the changelog thow there are not improvement related to this kind or problems.

What do you suggest? I need the nvidia driver in order to use the gpu for tensorflow related stuff...

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: not entirely sure what your question is. However, if you simply want your machine to not suspend; you can just use the extension [caffeine](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/). It is available on 22.04. You can find it in the extension manager.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion. It is indeed useful. Anyhow the problem I was facing was the following: randomly the pc goes to sleed even if you are using it. Sometimes it happens after few seconds you stop the mouse. For this reason I used the systemctl mask command. In that sense I should use caffeine while using all the time. I was asking if this is a known problem with amd ryzen cpus...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: Within 5 minutes of an event "going to sleep", the terminal command "sudo journalctl --since="-6 minutes"` will show system logs covering the event.

Comment: @ecatanzani if after installing caffeine and you are still have the same problem, you can try the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366417/random-reboots-on-20-04-lts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the question I was convinced the problem is due to the nvidia drivers, version 510. I tested a nunch of new drivers finding the same problem in both 510.60 and the latest 510.73.

Nvidia drivers 470 are good everything is working fine.

Thanks for your help.
Best

Comment: If this is an edit to your question, please edit the question. If this is an answer, please make the solution to your problem clear. As it is, this is not an answer, and does not belong in the answers section.